# Python interprets list as a tuple by mistake

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have this piece of code:

```
            for keys in self.keys:
                if has_classes := self.class_checker(keys[0]):
                    print(type(keys[0])) -> #just for demonstrating that it is actual list
                    keys[0] = [x for x in keys[0] if 'class="' not in x]
                    for classes in has_classes:
                        keys[0].append(f'class="{classes}"')
```

I want to change the list by using list comprehension and it is showing this error:

```
       <class 'list'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\USER\OneDrive\Desktop\XPATH\base\main.py", line 300, in <module>
    XPanther('<h1 class="Uo8X3b OhScic zsYMMe">Lidhjet e qasshmërisë</h1>',     'C:\\Users\\USER\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\XPATH\\xpath_test_case.txt').capture()
  File "C:\Users\USER\OneDrive\Desktop\XPATH\base\main.py", line 100, in capture
    keys[0] = [x for x in keys[0] if 'class="' not in x]
    ~~~~^^^
TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
```

As you can see on the first line of the error, it is printing the type of keys[0] as a list (which I also know is a list but anyways), and then it suddenly becomes a tuple ?

I'm very confused, please someone help me!

Comment: `keys[0]` is a list, but `keys` is likely not.

Comment: You cannot update a `tuple`. You meant to change the contents of the first list inside `keys`. You can do it like this: `keys[0][:] = [x for x in keys[0] if 'class="' not in x]`

Comment: When assigning to `keys[0]`, it's the type of `keys`, not `keys[0]`, that matters.

Comment: Yes , you are all right , thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @bereal has mentioned (and others..) in the comments of my post, the actual case for this problem is that I tried to change the contents of a list,which that list happens to be inside a tuple, which is immutable in itself, so i can't change it's values at all. The obvious solution would be to first transform the tuple into a list,then back again as a tuple if you want.